# Run-time Error '91': Excel 2011 for Mac VBA

Tags: vba, excel, osx-yosemite

I am creating a macro that pulls information from a weekly report into a master worksheet; I have gone through several steps but keep running into an error with my Cells.Find coding. I'm not sure why this is happening, as the Macro Recorder writes the same code, it's just a matter of replacing my manual entry with a variable.

Attached is the sub with the line in question **in bold**.

```
Sub Pull_W01_Data_Click()

Dim Advisor As Variant 'defines advisor name from first subroutine
Dim Buddy As Workbook 'defines xxx as destination file
Dim x As Workbook 'defines existing report file as source
Dim Destination As Range 'defines destination range of data pulled from report file

Advisor = Worksheets("Advisor Summary").Range("A1").Value
Set Buddy = Workbooks("file1name.xlsm")
Set x = Workbooks.Open("file2name.xlsm")
Set Destination = Workbooks("file1name.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("B2:S2")

'check if advisor name is entered
    If Advisor = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Your name is not visible; please start from the Reference tab.")
    Worksheets("Reference").Activate
    Exit Sub
End If

x.Activate
Cells.Find(What:=Advisor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$DQ$11").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Advisor
Range("A7:CD7").Select
Selection.Copy
Destination.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Line with run-time error 91:

> **Cells.Find(What:=Advisor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Activate**

Any ideas? Is my syntax off? Did I mess up with the name of the variables?

Comment: I think you need a range for find(). Instead of x.activate do something like `with x.range("A1:AA1000")` Edit: oh ooops, x is workbook. Set a worksheet first. Edit 2: also remove that `.activate` at the end.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Thing is, the data that I'll be pulling is on one of many available sheets...so I wanted to be able create a macro to search the entire workbook for the value captured by the dim Advisor (regardless of which sheet it's on), which would then activate that sheet and filter/copy/paste the data.

I actually played around with it a little bit and found a way to make it work...but it only pulls the data from the default worksheet of workbook x. So I'm having trouble with the find function, finding the **right** data based on the variable.

Comment: I don't think you can find across a workbook. Loop through all sheets?